# C# - Radio button Check Change Event not responding when checked

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

Please i have a radio button that i added dynamically from a list (gotten during database read), it displays fine, but it does not fire the check change event.

```
public void fillradioButton()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < officeLists.Count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton rbutton = new RadioButton()
        {
            Name = "rbutton",
            Text = candidate_surname + " " + candidate_name,
            Left = _RadiobuttonPos.X,
            Top = _RadiobuttonPos.Y,
        };

        this.Controls.Add(rbutton);
        _RadiobuttonPos.Y += 25;
    }
}

private void RadioButtonCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Okay I see U");                
}
```

Please i want the message box to show, if any radio button is checked.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the event to your radiobutton, for example:

```
 public void fillradioButton()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < officeLists.Count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton rbutton = new RadioButton()
        {
            Name = "rbutton",
            Text = candidate_surname + " " + candidate_name,
            Left = _RadiobuttonPos.X,
            Top = _RadiobuttonPos.Y,
        };

        If(i == 0) rbutton.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonCheckedChanged;

        this.Controls.Add(rbutton);
        _RadiobuttonPos.Y += 25;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another problem, the `MessageBox.Show("Okay I see U");  ` repeats twice when checked for the second option and once for the first.
i need it to show only once irrespective of the option selected. Thank You.

Comment: Try to add the event like this outside the for loop : this.Controls["rbutton"].CheckedChanged += RadioButtonCheckedChanged; What happends?

Comment: Actually try it now with the if, it is cleaner solution

Comment: thank you, now i need for the users to be able to select the radio button once, that is after clicking on a radio button it becomes disabled.

Comment: That's not relevant to this question any more. Anyway add something like rbutton.disabled = true; in your CheckedChanged event after showing the messagebox

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the click handler to the event on the radio button. At some point inside the loop after you init the radio button, do this:

```
rbutton.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButtonCheckedChanged);
```

Or

```
rbutton.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonCheckedChanged;
```

Since you are creating the button dynamically, [you need to manually wire up the event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfty2w4e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thank you for your help, `rbutton.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonCheckedChanged;` helped.
But the messagebox repeats twice when checked for the second option and once for the first. i need it to show only once irrespective of the option selected. Thank You.